# webpack 0.0.0.0 docker not working

Tags: django, docker, webpack, docker-compose, webpack-dev-server

I'm using docker-compose to serve django at 0.0.0.0:80 and webpack-dev-server at 0.0.0.0:3000. They're both work perfectly at 0.0.0.0

I also have domain bound to my external IP and I even can access django from this domain. But somehow, I can't access webpack-dev-server, neither by external IP, nor by domain.

Here is some additional data:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
 build: backend/
 command: sh dockerfiles/init.sh
 ports:
     - 0.0.0.0:80:80

js:
 build: webclient/
 command: yarn runserver
 ports:
     - 0.0.0.0:3000:3000
```

As you see, they are both served same way here

**server.js**

```
new WebpackDevServer(
        webpack(config),
        {
            publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
            hot: true,
            historyApiFallback: true,
            allowedHosts: [
                '0.0.0.0',
                'localhost',
                'DOMAIN',
                '*.DOMAIN'
            ],
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            }
        }
    ).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        console.log('Listening at 0.0.0.0:3000')
    })
```

When I ping the port 0.0.0.0:3000 - the port is open. When i ping DOMAIN:3000 - the port is closed.

Do you have any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `disableHostCheck`:

`{
            publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
            hot: true,
            historyApiFallback: true,
            disableHostCheck: true, // <------ here is the missing piece
            allowedHosts: [
                '0.0.0.0',
                'localhost',
                'DOMAIN',
                '*.DOMAIN'
            ],
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            }
        }`